Convergence of graph geodesics to geodesics on metric spaces
Let $(X,d)$ be a compact length space metric space $\mathbb{X}_{\delta}$ be a $\delta$-packing on $X$ and, for every $k\in \mathbb{N}_+$, let $G_{k,\delta}=(\mathbb{X}_{\delta},\mathcal{E}_k,W_k)$ where
$$
\{x,y\}\in \mathcal{E}_k \text{ iff } d(x,y)\le k\delta
$$
and where
$$
W(\{x,y\})=k\delta \text{ iff } (k-1)\delta < d(x,y)\le k\delta
.
$$
Let $d_{k,\delta}$ denote the shortest path distance on $G_k$ given by
$$
d_{k,\delta}(x,y) := \min \sum_{((u_i,u_{i+1}))_{i=1}^L;\,x=u_1;\,u^{L+1}=y}\, W(u_i,u_{i+1})
$$
where we minimize over all paths from $x$ to $y$.

Does $(G_{k,\delta},d_{k,\delta})$ coverage to $(X,d)$ in the Gromov-Hausdorff (or some other meaningful) sense?

Intuitively I'm asking: How many nearby points do I need to connect, to ensure that I can "consistently" approximate a metric space by a sequence of graph "discretizations"?

Don't the $\delta$-packings themselves already converge to $X$ in the Hausdorff metric on $X$ (and therefore the Gromov-Hausdorff metric)?

But the distance is being measured differently, its not exactly equal to the usual distance.  Also, Im wondering if there is a stronger sense in which this convergence happens...

Oh I see, I missed that part.

What are you doing with $k$ in terms of convergence? Are you keeping it fixed, or are you also varying it with $\delta$?

Ah, I'm letting it vary; initially I thought I can keep it fixed, but it seems more intuitive to me that it can grow as a function of $\delta$ (but not too fast).

I think you're going to have trouble if the metric is not intrinstic.

@JamesEHanson Good point, I was thinking simply connected is enough, buy you're definitely right.

Are you asking about the simultaneous limit for $(k,\delta)\to (\infty,0)$? Did you compute any examples, for instance, $X=[0,1]$ with the standard metric?

This is not a good example @MoisheKohan since the weight of each edge is exactly equal to the distance between those points.
